# Why isn't <br> displayed as break line in html?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am using a flask to make requests and display results in html page in my browser:

```
@api.route('/matcher', methods=['GET'])
def matcher():
    mid = request.args.get('id')
    text = get_text(id)
    parameter_data = {'enable': ['matcher']}
    result_dict = nlu.get_result(text, **parameter_data)

    return jsonify(result_dict)
```

The function get_result returns a dict, something as below:

```
{
"text": "This is a test",
"log": "log1 <br>log2<br>log3<br>",
"tags": {
"primary_tags": [],
"aux_tags": [],
 }
}
```

I hope the 
 tag in the filed 'log' will function as a break line when I make a request in my browser, but it seems it isn't interpreted as a html tag 'break line'. There is no break line in the html display.

How can I fix it?

The code to inject 
:

```
doc.log['log'] = '<br>'.join(self.log)
```

Comment: This looks more like a frontend error. How do you inject the tag into your html code? How is the injected html displayed in the F12 inspector?

Comment: The 'br' tag was inserted into the dict's log field before http request is made. The display in html inspector will be added. You can see the 'br' is part of a regular text, not html tag.

Comment: Can you show the code line in javascript where you inject the tag?

Comment: @Markus Please see my added code. I don't use javescript at all. Please see my def matcher() function above and that's how it is used in Flask.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I get you fully wrong, but from what I  can see your GET method returns pure JSON. There must be some javascript in the frontend to get the data from the JSON and inject it into the HTML DOM tree. At that point it is important, that you don’t escape the html formats.

Comment: Yes, result_dict is a pure python dict, and jsonify(result_dict) is probably pure JSON. I don't have any other code to do frontend stuff. Flask allows you to display the json in Browser nicely in a dict format. Now, I want to add some break lines to the multiple log messages to make them look clearer.

Comment: Well this approach is unusual to me. Anyways, if you use the browser to render JSON then you shouldn’t try html tags. Have you tried to simply put the log array into your log field without join? Which browser do you use?

Comment: Yes, it works without joining! Why is it that?

Comment: Your browser is able to render JSON, too. As you return JSON the browser switches to JSON mode. HTML tags will not be interpreted as such in JSON mode.

Comment: <br> or <br /> ?